# Closed form for subgroups of a set

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am working through an algebra text and am struggling to find the positive integer $k$ (in terms of $r$ and $s$ such that every nontrivial subgroup of the group $G=\{nr+ms\mid n,m\in \Bbb Z\}$ with $r$ and $s\in\Bbb Z$ takes the form $k\Bbb Z$.

For example, we know that for $\Bbb Z$ every nontrivial subgroup is of the form $k\Bbb Z$.

So far, I know that $G$ is cyclic as $\gcd(r,s)$ generates $G$. So we know that all subgroups of $G$ are cyclic but I am not sure how to use that or if that is even the correct method to approach this problem.

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Just edited it! Hopefully, that is more readable; never have used MathJax before.

Comment: I've made some adjustments. Do you mean to type $$G\color{red}{=}\{nr+ms\mid n,m\in \Bbb Z\}?$$ There's something not quite right about the question so far. Regardless, can you use Euclid's Algorithm?

Comment: I believe so. In the first part of the problem which is number 45 in section 1.6 in Fraleigh's Abstract Algebra we prove that that set G is a subgroup of Z (sorry for some reason I can't get Mathjax to work here but it was supposed to be $$G= {nr +ms | n,m \in \Bbb Z} is a subgroup of \Bbb Z). I am not sure how Euclid's would apply; I may just be missing the idea, however.

Comment: If $k$ is fixed, what do you mean by "takes the form $k\mathbb Z$"? Do you have your logical quantifiers in the right order? It sounds like you've figured out the important part, that $G=g\mathbb Z$. Note that this is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Oh! sorry we want to find such a k in terms of r and s for this problem.

Comment: Please [edit] the question accordingly

Comment: Should be easier to read now

Answer (score 1):

You've already figured out that $G = d\mathbb{Z}$ where $d = \gcd(r,s)$. So subgroups of $G$ correspond to subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ under the isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to G:x\to dx$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: So drawing this connection is where I have been struggling with; everything you wrote makes sense but I struggle to see how I can use this to find a k where kZ is the form of every subgroup.

Comment: A subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ is $b\mathbb{Z}$ where $b$ is some integer, so it is the cyclic group generated by $b$. What is the image of that cyclic group in $G$? (Hint: it is generated by the image of $b$).

Comment: Sorry for not being able to figure out how to type in MathJax but would it be something like the image of b-> dx?

Comment: So what I have is that every subgroup of G is of the form d*x*Z where d= gcd(r,s) and x is a positive integer?

Comment: Yes. Actually $x$ can be any integer, but $dx\mathbb{Z} = d(-x)\mathbb{Z}$.